# Flatten nested map into rows

Tags: clojure, nested-map

In clojure, how can I turn a nested map like this:

```
{"1" {"1.1" {}
      "1.2" {}}
 "2" {"2.1" {}
      "2.2" {}
      "2.3" {}}}
```

Into this:

```
[["1" "1.1"]
 ["1" "1.2"]
 ["2" "2.1"]
 ["2" "2.2"]
 ["2" "2.3"]]
```

Provided that nesting is not limited

Comment: Step of recursion: `(defn rows-step [v rows] (->> rows (map #(concat [v] %))))`
Recursion: `(defn rows [data] (if (empty? data) [] ...)`

Comment: cfrick, Do I understand correctly that this cannot be done using tail recursion?

Comment: cfrick, thank you very much!